# Making the translucent backface glossy

Tags: materials, shaders, photorealism, pbr

I'm working on photorealistic leaf material that works fine with a **plane mesh** (of course if it had real geometry thickness the effect would have been easy to set up but heavy for rendering). This is my setup so far:
[image: Material setup]

If you're wondering about the Fresnel thing, it's explained [here](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/diffuse-translucency-way-too-difficult-to-set-up-in-cycles/807). The entire setup is copied from the same guide.

But now my problem is that **the backface has no glossy**. It's just the diffuse light of the translucency effect.

[image]

I know that the down side of real leaves are not as glossy as their top side but there's still a subtle gloss. How can I add a Glossy BSDF For the backface?

Comment: Hi :). You'd need to basically rebuild the Principled BSDF from scratch using other shaders. I did that for another answer, and included that as a nodegroup :))

Comment: Related question with nodegroup included: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/215782/78972

Comment: Wow. You have the same setup like mine but you've just seperated the roughness for the two sides. Mine had the glossy effect too but I couldn't control it individually so I thought it was not there. Thanks. You're node group has more controls and is applicable for various cases, especially more complex ones. I'd appreciate it if you post the same images and blend files here as an answer so that I can accept it and give you the bounty.

Comment: @JachymMichal Submit an answer please

Comment: Posted an answer so your bounty isn't wasted :)). cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Posting my own [copied answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/218088/78972) just so Barbod M's bounty isn't wasted :))</sup>

The [linked devtalk post](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/diffuse-translucency-way-too-difficult-to-set-up-in-cycles/807) already offers a setup for correct backface reflections.
To fine-tune roughness for Frontface/Backface, split the node-tree into two branches.

I used a custom-built PBR shader incorporating Translucency, following [CynicatPro's approach](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlH00768JwqG4__RRtKACofTztc0Owys8).
But you can use a simpler setup as long as the roughness channel is split.

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

For convenience, I [packed the whole setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifBzN.png) into a nodegroup called *Principled Leaves BSDF*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just for reference - I used this nodegorup for all foliage in [one of my archviz projects](https://www.behance.net/gallery/136125335/Edith-Farnsworth-House-1951-Full-CGI) and it turned out pretty good :))